# Not able to get speed from gps on phone

Tags: android, gps, android-gps

I have code which correctly calculates the speed using Service but i am unable to transfer the speed data to my Activity.The speed correctly displays inside onLocationChanged but when i try to get this speed data using gps.getspeed it returns 0.I am not able to understand why i am unable to transfer this data using the getter function.

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {


    Context mContext;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    String format_speed="0";

    public GPSTracker(){

    }
    public static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_IDENTIFIER = 1;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;


    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public static boolean checkPermission(final Context context) {
        return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            checkPermission(mContext);
            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    Log.d("Network", "Network");

                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }

                    }


                }

                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                0,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     */

    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            checkPermission(mContext);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     */

    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     */

    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    public String getspeed(){

        return format_speed;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     *
     * @return boolean
     */

    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     */

    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double lat = (double) (location.getLatitude());
        double lng = (double) (location.getLongitude());

        double speed = 0;
        if (this.mLastLocation != null){

            speed=1000*18/5*distance(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),lat,mLastLocation.getLongitude(),lng,0.0,0.0)/(location.getTime() - this.mLastLocation.getTime());
            if (UnitLocale.getDefault() == UnitLocale.Imperial) {
                speed = speed * 0.621371;
            }
            else{
                speed = speed ;
            }

            if(speed>200){
                speed=0;
            }

        }

        this.mLastLocation = location;

        // format_speed=df2.format(speed);
        int a = (int) Math.round(Math.abs(speed));
        format_speed=String.valueOf(a);
        Log.v("speedgps2",format_speed);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public double distance(double lat1, double lat2, double lon1,
                           double lon2, double el1, double el2) {

        final int R = 6371; // Radius of the earth

        Double latDistance = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
        Double lonDistance = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
        Double a = Math.sin(latDistance / 2) * Math.sin(latDistance / 2)
                + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2))
                * Math.sin(lonDistance / 2) * Math.sin(lonDistance / 2);
        Double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        double distance = R * c * 1000; // convert to meters

        double height = el1 - el2;

        distance = Math.pow(distance, 2) + Math.pow(height, 2);

        return Math.sqrt(distance);
    }


}
```

In my Activity OnCreate i have

GPSService gps;

and then a function to get location data

```
public void getlocationdata(){
        gps = new GPSTracker(TripActivity.this);

        // check if GPS enabled
        if(gps.canGetLocation()){

            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

            latinit = String.valueOf(latitude);
            loninit = String.valueOf(longitude);
            speed=gps.getspeed();

            // \n is for new line
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: "+ latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.v("location",latinit+"  "+loninit);
        }else{
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: In my Activity when i give speed=gps.getspeed() it always returns 0.

Comment: What is gps here and how you are getting this?

Comment: gps is my instantiation of GPSService. I just added some more code of how it plays out in Activity.

Comment: @NigamPatro..do you need more information? I am really stuck here..Please help

Comment: But, the process of starting service is wrong. Is `onLocationChanged()` getting called?

Comment: @NigamPatro OnLocation called is getting called only in service to get speed because i want users to know the speed even when the app is in background

Comment: But, the process of starting service is wrong. Get some knwoledge about that at first.

Comment: @NigamPatro..I am starting the service inside my Activity..what is wrong about that?

Comment: `startService(new Intent(TripActivity.this, GPSTracker.class));` this way need to start a service and also need to specify the Service in AndroidManifest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129401/discussion-between-n-czar-and-nigam-patro).

Comment: `The speed correctly displays inside onLocationChanged`. ?? Where and how exactly? Why dont you try to transfer `speed` instead of that `format_speed` string with intermediate rounding and use of an integer?